# How to change min value to current page when button is pressed in input range?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to change the value like this when I press the next button while on the current page.

[image: like this]

I wrote the code like this, but it doesn't work at all:

```js
el.delegate(".nextbtn", "click", function (event) {
  const current = $(event.currentTarget) // =.nextbtn
  const currentR = $(".pagination-range")
  let pageNumber = +currentR.val() // =currentPage
  let minV = +currentR.attr("min")
  let maxV = +currentR.attr("max")

  if (self.getTotalPage >= maxV) {
    currentR.attr({
      min: pageNumber,
      max: pageNumber + 4,
    })
  }
})
```

What's wrong with this code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `+currentR` ? Why the + sign here ?

Comment: @user3045457 I guess its the bad naming.

POP can you create codepen example?

Comment: @user3045457 Because I wanted to convert this value to a number.

Comment: @Kudlas I will make it. Please wait.

Comment: For converting I would rather use parseInt() function (or parseFloat)

Comment: Thank you, @Kudlas & really sorry everyone.
This pagination was customized by myself for the input range, but I don't know why it works. Even if I copy-pasted it, it didn't work and I couldn't create the same situation as local..
I couldn't make code that works with codepen, so I'll start again. I apologize for the inconvenience. :'(

Answer (score 0):

Here is pure javascript solution for you. I defined my own $ as shorthand function, which utilizes querySelector, so its similar to jQuery.

```js
const $ = (s) => document.querySelector(s);

const rng = $("#rng");
const button = $("#biggerMax");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("adding max value by 4");
  let rngMax = rng.getAttribute("max");
  let newMax = parseInt(rngMax)+4;
  rng.setAttribute("max", newMax );
});
```

```html
<input id="rng" type=range min=2 max=5 step=1>

<button id="biggerMax">Bigger max</button>
```